# Using pandas library without bz2 (No root access, can't install bz2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bz2

I am trying to run a python code which uses `pandas` library. I am getting an error saying that `bz2` can not be found. I do not have root access and can not install anything. **Is there a way to use `pandas` in another way?** *There are similar questions to mine in stackoverflow but they require root access to install `bz2`.*

Importing `pandas` (Python 3.8.3, CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)):

```py
import pandas as pd
```

output:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/home/myusername/src/dataprocessing/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev  # pyright: ignore # noqa:F401
  File "/home/myusername/src/dataprocessing/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    import pandas.compat.compressors
  File "/home/myusername/src/dataprocessing/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/compat/compressors.py", line 7, in <module>
    import bz2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bz2'
```

Comment: `bz2` is in the python standard library. Did you build python from source?

Comment: @erip I have no idea, this is a remote server and I just checked and found out that python is installed.

Answer (score 0):

If `bz2` is not mandatory, you can try to catch the exception:

```
try:
    import pandas as pd
except ModuleNotFoundError as err:
    print(err)
```

**Update**

You can also copy [`bz2.py`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python/cpython/3.8/Lib/bz2.py) module from `GitHub`

Answer (score 0):

`bz2` might not exist if Python hasn't been built to include it.

It's definitely a hack, but you could create a dummy empty `bz2.py` in your working directory, and hope Pandas doesn't need to access any attributes from it at import time.